# Count not load type [ProjectName].WebAPIApplication on Web API project

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I have a .Net Web Application using the Web.API Project Properties show it is using .Net 4.5

In my web page the following code calls one of methods.

```
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '/Appointments/GetMissingKeys',
                    data:  $('#mrnList').val()                      
                }).done(function() {
                    alert('done!');
                }).fail(function (Status, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Error: ' + Status.status + ' - ' + Status.statusText);
                }).always(function () {
                    alert('All done or not');
                });
```

This in turn should be calling the following

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MRNInput.Controllers
{
    public class AppointmentController : ApiController
    {
        [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
        [Route("Appointments/GetMissingKeys")]
        HttpResponseMessage GetMissingAppointmentKeys([FromBody]String MRNList)
        {
            HttpResponseMessage resp = null;

            resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
            return resp;
        }
    }
}
```

When I check the status object I am getting an internal server error (500) and the response says the following

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'MRNInput.WebApiApplication'.

Source Error: 


Line 1:  <%@ Application Codebehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="MRNInput.WebApiApplication" Language="C#" %>


Source File: /global.asax    Line: 1 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18408
```

I did check the code of Global.asax.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MRNInput
{
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        }
    }
}
```

Now apart from the .Net version in the error page - cannot see why it cannot load this last class. If it is the .Net version reported in the error how can I get it to run under the correct .Net version (4.5)

Comment: does it make a difference if you make your api method public?

Comment: also, is that the right url, or should it be api/appointments/getmissingkeys?

Comment: Just tried that and still get 404 error. Not sure if it might have something to do with the page being in the root of the site and not in the views directory. Text message that goes with the error is {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:51520/api/Appointments/GetMissingKeys'.","MessageDetail":"No type was found that matches the controller named 'Appointments'."}

Comment: That's because your controller is APPOINTMENT (singular) and you're calling AppointmentS plural. Get rid of the 's' in your api call.

Comment: ***I am voting to close***, because OP solved the problem by **Clean Solution**. Paul - please create a new question for *it cannot find the Appointments/GetMissingKeys*. If you update your question, all answers will be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well that was easy(ish)

Select the BUILD menu, then the 'Clean Solution' option.

That gets rid of the 'Could not load type [ProjectName].WebAPIApplication on Web API project' error - now to deal with routing as it cannot find the Appointments/GetMissingKeys :(

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes:

```
namespace MRNInput.Controllers
{
    public class AppointmentController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpPost, Route("api/Appointments/GetMissingKeys")]
        public IHttpActionResult GetMissingAppointmentKeys([FromBody]string MRNList)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}

$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: '/api/Appointments/GetMissingKeys',
   data:  $('#mrnList').val() //ensure you have a value here,
   datatype: "json" //<-- note the additional property                     
})
```

I would also suggest adding this to your startup.cs to handle automatic camel casing.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().Configure<MvcOptions>(options =>
    {
       options.OutputFormatters.OfType<JsonOutputFormatter>()
       .First()
       .SerializerSettings
       .ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that your js api call is looking for Appointment*s* and your controller is Appointment.  Try this

```
[RoutePrefix("api/Appointments")]
public class AppointmentController : ApiController
{
    [AcceptVerbs("Post")]
    [Route("GetMissingKeys")]
    HttpResponseMessage GetMissingAppointmentKeys([FromBody]String MRNList)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage resp = null;

        resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
        return resp;
    }
}
```